# Sending auto replies in Office 365 based on message contents

Tags: gmail, office-365

I want to be able to search each email I receive for a word and, if found, autoreply with Office 365 email. I couldn't find a way to do this (only unconditionally), so I set up the email to forward to my Gmail account, and from there set up a filter that then sends a canned response.

Unfortunately, this doesn't work quite as expected. It sends the canned response to my Office 365 email.

So basically it is currently: `sender -> 365@office` forwarded to Gmail, then `Gmail -> 365@office`

What I want is: `sender -> 365@office` forwarded to Gmail, then `Gmail -> sender`

Of course, if there is a way to do this in Office 365 itself without requiring Gmail that would be even better.